# How to trim and match columns to obtain the common time values and corresponding values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The equipment (two scopes) give data in different number of points, and triggers in the same moment (0 on time column). (No chance to find same settings).

What I would like to achieve is to align the time with its corresponding values (if missing it may be interpolated, data doesn't change fast here).

How to achieve this trim and match data along two dataframes?

As an example I have prepared two data sets: one comes from scope1 (more datapoints), and other data comes from scope2 (less datapoints). This is just an example, in reality I got 20k samples from scope1 and 10k samples from other.

```
scope1Data = pd.DataFrame({
'TIME': [-1, -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1],
'V': [-0.841470985, -0.78332691, -0.717356091, -0.644217687, -0.564642473, -0.479425539, -0.389418342, -0.295520207, -0.198669331, -0.099833417, 0, 0.099833417, 0.198669331, 0.295520207, 0.389418342, 0.479425539, 0.564642473, 0.644217687, 0.717356091, 0.78332691, 0.841470985],
})

scope2Data = pd.DataFrame({
'TIME': [-1.05, -0.9, -0.75, -0.6, -0.45, -0.3, -0.15, 0, 0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75, 0.9, 1.05]
'I': [-0.887362369, -0.946300088, -0.983985947, -0.999573603, -0.992712991, -0.963558185, -0.91276394, -0.841470985, -0.751280405, -0.644217687, -0.522687229, -0.389418342, -0.247403959, -0.099833417, 0.049979169]
})
```

The best would be to start from zero time (somewhere in the middle) and match time from scope1 to time of scope2. The missing values may be extrapolated, or I can change number of datapoints from faster scope (scope1). Extra values from faster scope may be discarded. Saying simplier, data for time from -1.05 to 1.05 is sufficient, the rest may be trimmed off.

Also, the column TIME from scope2 will be not required anymore.

I am not expecting full answer, of course more is better; just the naming of this process would suffice.

The desired output format can be:

```
 combinedData = pd.DataFrame({
 'TIME': [-0.9, -0.75, -0.6, -0.45, -0.3, -0.15, 0, 0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75, 0.9]
 'V': [corresponding values]
 'I': [corresponding-iterpolated-values-if-not-available-from-data]
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the answer below, I've used `numpy` to interpolate the scope2 data onto the scope1 time axis. I've also included plotting for visualising the results.

[image]

Imports and data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#The data
scope1Data = pd.DataFrame({
'TIME': [-1, -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2,
         -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1],
'V': [-0.841470985, -0.78332691, -0.717356091, -0.644217687, -0.564642473,
      -0.479425539, -0.389418342, -0.295520207, -0.198669331, -0.099833417,
      0, 0.099833417, 0.198669331, 0.295520207, 0.389418342, 0.479425539,
      0.564642473, 0.644217687, 0.717356091, 0.78332691, 0.841470985],
})

scope2Data = pd.DataFrame({
'TIME': [-1.05, -0.9, -0.75, -0.6, -0.45, -0.3, -0.15, 0, 0.15,
         0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75, 0.9, 1.05],
'I': [-0.887362369, -0.946300088, -0.983985947, -0.999573603, -0.992712991,
      -0.963558185, -0.91276394, -0.841470985, -0.751280405, -0.644217687,
      -0.522687229, -0.389418342, -0.247403959, -0.099833417, 0.049979169]
})
```

Interpolation, and put the results in a new dataframe.

```
#interpolate scope2 data onto the time axis of scope1
scope2_interpolated = np.interp(x=scope1Data['TIME'],
                                xp=scope2Data['TIME'],
                                fp=scope2Data['I'])
#Put it in a dataframe
scope2_interpolated = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': scope1Data['TIME'],
    'I_scope2_interp': scope2_interpolated,
     })

#new dataframe that has both scope1 and the interpolated scope2
combined_data = pd.merge(scope1Data, scope2_interpolated, on='TIME')

#Optionally rename columns
combined_data = combined_data.rename(columns={'TIME': 'TIME_scope1', 'V': 'V_scope1'})
```

Visualise the results

```
#As a sanity check, visualise the results.
#Interpolated should overlay with the original scope2 data
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 3))
ax1.plot(combined_data.TIME_scope1, combined_data.V_scope1,
         linewidth=2, label='V [scope1]')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (ms)')
ax1.set_ylabel('V (mV)')
ax1.legend()

ax1.grid(axis='x', which='both')
ax1.set_title('Original and interpolated scope data')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(scope2Data.TIME, scope2Data.I, label='original I [scope2]',
         color='tab:red', marker='d', linestyle='')
ax2.plot(combined_data.TIME_scope1, combined_data.I_scope2_interp,
         color='tab:red', linestyle=':', label='interpolated I [scope2]')
ax2.set_ylabel('I (mA)')
ax2.legend(loc='lower right')

#Rather than trimming the data, you can trim the
# plot limits if you only want to see a smaller range
x_limits = [-1.2, 1.2]
ax1.set_xlim(x_limits);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to concatenate `Time1` and `Time2` into `Time`, sort `Time` with `np.argsort`. Then use `np.interp(Time, Time1, V)` to acquire linearly interpolated `V` values, same for `I`.

A more cumbersome way is to use `numpy.searchsorted` for each of the `scope2Data Time` elements and then insert it with `numpy.insert` providing us with full `Time` array. (`np.searchsorted` returns the indice where the element should be inserted to maintain order of `scope1Data`) So we have `Time` array with no missing values and incomplete `V, I` arrays. Then you may want to interpolate with `numpy.interp`